# What are all the versions of Gary?

Tags: character-identification, final-space

In *Final Space* season 1 chapter 8 Gary goes to visit the imprisoned Titan, Bolo. When he first "meets" Bolo he sees multiple versions of himself and comments on a few:

- Construction Hat Gary
- Eagle Face Gary
- Cookie Headed Gary
- Little Micro Gary
- Amazing Moustache Gary

There are many others in the background, what are they all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my counting of the scene there are 44 Garys shown in the scene with only the 5 mentioned in the question as being named. The rest, therefore, will be named the best I can but they won't be the "official" names of the characters. The official named characters are in bold.

[image: Garys 1 - 5]

1. Blue Alien Gary with Tail
2. Red Robot Gary
3. Hawaiin Shirt Gary
4. Skeleton Gary
5. Wizard Gary

[image: Garys 6 - 8]

6. Matrix Gary
7. Flame Shirt Gary
8. Clown Gary

[image: Garys 9 - 15]

9. Scuba Diver Gary
10. Blue Glow Gary
11. Punk Rocker Gary
12. Cowboy Gary
13. Einstein Gary
14. Arctic Explorer Gary
15. Butler in the Buff Gary

[image: Garys 16 - 18]

16. Long Hair Gary
17. Captain Gary
18. Pirate Gary

[image: Garys 19 - 20]

19. Balloon Head Gary
20. No Eyes Gary

[image: Garys 21 - 25]

21. 80's Musician Gary
22. Shrimp Gary
23. Flower/Daisy Gary
24. **Construction Hat Gary**
25. Lip Face Gary

[image: Garys 26 - 30]

26. Sweater Vest Gary
27. Scene Kid Gary
28. **Eagle Face Gary**
29. Lobster Claws Gary
30. Pistol Head Gary

[image: Garys 31 - 35]

31. **Cookie Headed Gary**
32. Confused Gary
33. Tourist Gary
34. Advanced Robot Gary
35. Dog Gary

[image: Garys 36 - 39]

36. Horse Rider Gary
37. Shark Gary
38. **Little Micro Gary**
39. Gary Holding Crabs Gary

[image: Garys 40 - 44]

40. Mullet Gary
41. Body Builder Gary
42. Superhero Gary
43. **Amazing Moustache Gary**
44. Crowned Dressing Gown Gary

Comment: It would be helpful if you could rotate the various Garys and place them into a single line. Thanks

Comment: @Valorum If I get bored later on your wish is my command.